# Detect non-standard scrollbars

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, scrollbar

Is there a way to detect with WinAPI if window has non-standard scrollbars (for example, window can draw scrollbars itself instead of using standard ones)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if this will work, but it is just an idea.
Scroll bars belong to the window which has to be created with this style enabled. So, you can check if your window contains WS_VSCROLL style and if so - this is standard scrollbar. In counterpart it is drawn by somebody else.

You can check it on this way:

```
// Assume that a window handle hWnd is known
int style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
BOOL bStandard = ((style & WS_VSCROLL) != 0);
```

Comment: Then there's the case of using 'scroll bar controls' as opposed to using window styles. Dunno if they'd count as *non-standard scrollbars*. +1 nevertheless, I believe this is all that could be done.

Comment: @clumpter - It is the point. If the scrollbar is standard, then bStandard will be true. Otherwise (non-standard scrollbar in the windown hWnd, or there is no scrollbars) it will be false. It means, you have to be sure that hWnd contains a scrollbar and this is a way to find out if it is a standard scrollbar.

Comment: That's the point, Vladimir. How can i be sure that window contains a scrollbar if my question is "How can i be sure that window contains a scrollbar?"? Did you got it?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to see how you could do this. A control could just paint scroll bars in its own canvas, do its own hit testing and how would you possibly know. You could do all this without creating separate HWNDs for the scroll bars.

What would be more interesting would be if you could say why you would wish to know this.